# ¿Cómo ingresar al evento Layout en datagridview?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, layout, datagridview

Creé este evento cuando un usuario hace clic en una celda de otro datagridview

```
private void grdDET_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        //grdDET.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowFiltering = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        //grdDET.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderClickAction = HeaderClickAction.SortSingle;

        try
        {
            //HEADER
            DataGridView dataGridView;
            dataGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            DataGridViewBand oBand = dataGridView.Columns[0];

            if (oBand.DataGridView.Columns.Contains("VerCFD") == false) oBand.DataGridView.Columns.Add("VerCFD","");
            if (oBand.DataGridView.Columns.Contains("VerAperak") == false) oBand.DataGridView.Columns.Add("VerAperak","");

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn oCol in oBand.DataGridView.Columns)
            {
                switch (oCol.Name)
                {
                    case "Serie":
                        oCol.HeaderCell.Value = "Series";
                        oCol.HeaderCell.ReadOnly = true;
                        oCol.Width = 60;
                        break;
                    //case "Folio":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "Folio";
                    //    oCol.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
                    //    oCol.CellAppearance.TextHAlign = Infragistics.Win.HAlign.Right;
                    //    oCol.Width = 70;
                    //    break;
                    //case "FechaFactura":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "Factura Factura";
                    //    oCol.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
                    //    oCol.Width = 100;
                    //    break;
                    //case "FechaRecibo":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "Fecha de Recibo";
                    //    oCol.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
                    //    oCol.Width = 100;
                    //    break;
                    //case "Status":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "Status";
                    //    oCol.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
                    //    oCol.Width = 80;
                    //    break;
                    //case "Resultado":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "Resultado";
                    //    oCol.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
                    //    oCol.Width = 150;
                    //    break;
                    //case "FolioAtencion":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "Fol. Atn.";
                    //    oCol.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
                    //    oCol.Width = 80;
                    //    break;
                    //case "VerCFD":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "";
                    //    oCol.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.Button;
                    //    oCol.CellAppearance.TextHAlign = Infragistics.Win.HAlign.Center;
                    //    oCol.Width = 50;
                    //    break;
                    //case "VerAperak":
                    //    oCol.Header.Caption = "";
                    //    oCol.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.Button;
                    //    oCol.CellAppearance.TextHAlign = Infragistics.Win.HAlign.Center;
                    //    oCol.Width = 50;
                    //    break;
                    default:
                        oCol.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación y pongo un punto de interrupción en ese evento, el programa no ingresa a este evento

este es el código donde debe llamar el evento de layout pero no lo hace

```
private void grdHDR_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            string CadenaConexion = string.Empty;
            DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
            if (ValidaDatos())
            {
                #region Consulta
                CadenaConexion = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)(cboAmbiente.Items[cboAmbiente.SelectedIndex])).Value;
                db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(CadenaConexion);

                string Folio_Inicial = string.Empty;
                string Folio_Final = string.Empty;
                string RFC = string.Empty;
                //string Desc_Emisor = string.Empty;
                //Int32 Id_Num_Prov = 0;

                Folio_Inicial = txtFolioIni.Text.Trim();
                Folio_Final = txtFolioFin.Text.Trim();
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = grdHDR.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    grdDET.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    //txt3_prov.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    RFC = row.Cells["RFC"].Value.ToString();
                }


                //try
                //{
                //    Id_Num_Prov = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmisor.Text.Trim());
                //}
                //catch
                //{
                //    Desc_Emisor = txtEmisor.Text.Trim();
                //}

                try
                {
                    sp = db.GetStoredProcCommand("eDocResumenEmisor_pUP");

                    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pCveOperacion", DbType.String, "D");

                    if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(Folio_Inicial))
                        db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pFolio_Inicial", DbType.Int32, Folio_Inicial);

                    if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(Folio_Final))
                        db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pFolio_Final", DbType.Int32, Folio_Final);

                    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pFec_Ini", DbType.DateTime, dtFechaInicial.Value);
                    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pFec_Fin", DbType.DateTime, dtFechaFinal.Value);
                    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pRFC", DbType.String, RFC);

                    //if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(Desc_Emisor))
                    //    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pDesc_Emisor", DbType.String, Desc_Emisor);

                    //if (Id_Num_Prov != 0)
                    //    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pId_Num_Prov", DbType.Int32, Id_Num_Prov);

                    //sp.CommandTimeout = 60000;
                    oDs = db.ExecuteDataSet(sp);

                    if (oDs.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //grdDET.DataSource = oDs;
                        grdDET.DataSource = oDs.Tables[0];
                        //grdHDR.DataBind();

                        lblDET.Text = "Se encontraron " + oDs.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString() + " CFD's";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                #endregion

                DesHabilita();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

¿Cuál es la forma de hacer que ingrese al evento de layout? Pensé que con el evento de layout es correcto, pero no estoy seguro.

¿también puede decirme si la forma en que agregué columnas a otro datagridview es correcta?

gracias y saludos

Comment: En tu código de evento `grdHDR_CellMouseClick(` no encontré ninguna llamada explicita al procedimiento `grdDET_Layout` que dices que es el evento `Layout` de un `DataGridView`, tampoco la hay de manera implicita, pues el evento `Layout` se lanza cuando se rediseña el `DataGridView` en tu código las referencias al `DataGridView` con nombre `grdDET` que parece ser el que lanza el evento `grdDET_Layout`, solo dos referencias: `grdDET.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` y `grdDET.DataSource = oDs.Tables[0]`, cambia valores asociados, pero no diseño, por tanto el evento `Layout` no se lanzará.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero ya no use ese evento